# Architecture ideas to allow customers to build their own site, based off external site's data?

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system

I'm not entirely sure how to properly ask this, so please bear with me.

I have an idea for a site I would like to build, which would basically be a site for members to create some data and have it housed in my database.  I would like to offer a value-add to the site which would allow people to spin off their own website via my own "website builder" tool (probably some sort of CMS).  Their website would be able to communicate with my master database to display their data.

Getting down to the crux of the topic, I'm looking for architectural advice/ideas/etc. regarding what services I could use to do this.  I'm not looking a 100% automated solution, but something along these lines (which may not be completely correct, I admit):

- Customer puts in an order to create their own site, using my tools.
- I setup a separate domain for them, roll out the CMS foundation to the site, and the customer has full editing control of the CMS to design it however they would like.
- The CMS would have some customizations so that it includes functionality to call APIs located on the master site, which would return the relevant data.

In the research I have done on SO, I've seen a lot of mentions of Umbraco which honestly looks like a good start.  I'm just worried that when I go to upgrade a version, I have to deal with overwriting my custom API functionality.  I'm guessing this is the nature of the beast, and requires me to accept/plan for it.

Does anyone have any thoughts about this?  Some high-level starting points?  Thanks!

Comment: there are so many of those CMS / blog engines / DNN and so on... why do you want to reinvent such thing?! I know this does not answer your question but I am curious.

Comment: Are you sure you want to limit yourself to asp.net solutions? You'll find many more choices in the LAMP world.

Comment: @DavidePiras: I'm not really looking to reinvent (actually, I'd prefer NOT to reinvent).  Do you have ideas as to how I can use existing services to my advantage?

Comment: @LarryK: Yes, I'm sure :)  I'm 100% looking for something in the ASP.NET world.

Answer (score -1):

I've been thinking about this same issue for my customers.

It is not hard to automatically roll out a stock cms such as Wordpress or Joomla. This sort of thing is done all the time by "1 click installers" that DreamHost and others have.

Including custom widgets or plugins for the CMS that can connect to your main app is also not hard.

For dns, you can use [Amazon Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2010/12/06/announcing-amazon-route-53-dns-service/) or other DNS services that include a good api at the dns management level.

I suggest that you focus on using a CMS that is very popular (eg Wordpress or Joomla) rather than something less well known such as Umbraco. Using a more popular system will drastically reduce your training costs--remember that if you supply the CMS to your customers, then they'll also expect you to supply the support for it...

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  I'm not looking to use Wordpress or Joomla, or something that's not ASP.NET based (hence the ASP.NET tag).